# Why doesn't incremented reputation, according to upvoted?

Tags: discussion

I got 33 upvoted in the [Answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/40989/is-a-married-person-looking-at-an-unmarried-person/40990#40990),

but the score incremented only around 200. Why?

Note: Sorry for my poor English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [daily reputation cap](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32160/what-is-the-daily-reputation-cap-and-how-can-i-hit-it): you can only get 200 rep points every day from upvotes.

Comment: Thank you very much for clear my doubt....